# $p^n+1=k^3$ where $p$ is a prime and $k$ is a positive integer.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

My problem:

> Find all the prime numbers $p$ for which there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $p^n+1$ is a cube of a positive integer.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If $p^n+1=m^3$, then $p^n=m^3-1=(m-1)(m^2+m+1)=(m-1)[(m-1)(m+2)+3]$. The gcd of $m-1$ and $(m-1)(m+2)+3$ must divide $3$. Therefore it is either $1$ or $3$. The only form it is $1$, while their product is divisible by only one prime, is if $m-1=1$. This gives the solution $m=2,p=7,n=1$. Otherwise $3$ divides $m-1$ and therefore $p=3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p^n+1=k^3\Rightarrow p^n=(k^3-1)=(k-1)(k^2+k+1)\Rightarrow (k-1)=1$. (As an exercise, prove to yourself that $k-1\ne p^m$)

$k=2\Rightarrow p=7,\ n=1$